# Is it safe to kiss my cat on lips?

Tags: cats, diseases

I have an indoor cat. She is never allowed outside. She has been given every possible vaccination. She gets regular bath with cat soap. And she gets to eat only hygienic cat food.

So is it safe to kiss her on lips. Is there any chance of spread of disease?

NOTE: I have seen such things in youtube. That's why I am wondering.

In the site https://www.vetwest.com.au/pet-library/kissing-your-cat

It is given,

> As such, at any point in time, a cat's mouth may be no dirtier than ours. However, cats contain certain other bacteria in their mouths, which cause gum disease. As predators, they also eat animals and insects that may harbor diseases. To be safe, avoid kissing your cat on the lips.

My cat is predator in no sense, as she is indoor and I have never seen her eating insects.

There is another question which is somewhat like this. [Is it safe to hug and kiss indoor cats?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11157/is-it-safe-to-hug-and-kiss-indoor-cats)

But there the specific word of **not kissing on the lip** is written.

And my question is exclusively about **kissing on the lip**.

The two are clearly not duplicate.